# What is the difference between "M.2 PCIe NVMe" and "M.2 2280, PCIe-NVMe, TLC"

Tags: ssd

Just trying to figure out what is the difference between `M.2 PCIe NVMe` and `M.2 2280, PCIe-NVMe, TLC` ??

I need to choose one.

I mean which one is better?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Is it just the length of the chip in mm? And no difference in the performance?

Comment: All the "facts" of the latter one also apply to the other one. The only distinction would be TLC, which results in 3 bits being stored per cell, and usually results in slightly lower speed and durability compared to SLC SSDs - which only store one bit per physical cell.
Chances are the other one is TLC too though, especially since it's the same price.

Comment: It seems like both 256GB and both 512GB SSDs could be duplicate options in their system because they are the same price, but they *could* be different models/brands! You should ask this retailer/company what the difference is because the first option could also be a 2280 (22mm x 80mm) SSD with TLC memory. No way to know without the exact model number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeating comments as an answer.

2280 is the size designation for an M.2 card, such as an SSD. This is the typical size for a PC.

TLC is the type of memory used in the drive. It stands for *Three Level Cell* which means that each cell holds three bits. This is again typical for a consumer drive. MLCs, with two bits per cell, are used in high-end drives like the Samsung Pro series, while QLC, with four bits, are used in low-end drives like the Intel 660p.

While this is likely a duplicate entry, but personally I would pick the one with more details, otherwise you could get a terribly overpriced Intel 660p.

If that price is in USD the drive is expensive anyways - if you can and are able to put in the drive yourself, get something like the Kingston A2000 which has a suggested price of 99 USD for a 1 TB model. It should be good enough for any non professional uses.

Comment: Thanks for kind reply and comments @Jan. Well, I can't buy separately as trying to buy a Lenovo machine here in New Zealand and these are the options in the customization that I can chose/change. Will ask for more details though. Appreciated :)

Comment: @ViKiNG I just looked at a quick conversion which says 150 NZD is 100 USD - that disk is still overpriced unless it's a high-end TLC.

Comment: Thanks Jan. Much appreciated :). I'll make sure if it's worth buying :)

Comment: @ViKiNG if you want to play games you don't have much choice - unless there are other drives available - since 256 GB is too little for modern games.

Comment: Strongly Agreed.